# Validar formulario con JS

Tags: php, javascript

Quiero validar un formulario con js a través de un alert

Mi código es el siguiente pero no me está funcionando

He quitado el type="submit" del botón, ya que sino, siempre confirma el formulario

```js
function security(){
  var mensaje = confirm("¿Estás seguro de que quieres BORRAR este aviso?");
if (mensaje) {
  var theForm = document.forms['formborrar'];
  theForm.submit();
}
else {
}
}
```

```html
<form action="borrar.php" method="post" name="formborrar">
  <input type="text" name="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" style="display: none;">
  <input class="btn" onclick="security()" type="submit" value="Borrar Aviso" name="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: *Validar* se suele usar para la acción de comprobar que los campos del formulario son *válidos*. Creo que el término más apropiado sería *Confirmar*. En cualquier caso... ¿Qué es lo que no funciona?

Comment: El alert me aparece, pero al pulsar la opcion de aceptar, no lo confirma. Parece que el if de la funcion no funciona

Comment: ¿Qué problema estás teniendo? La condición debería de funcionar correctamente. Haciendo pruebas con tu código, el submit se está enviando sin problemas.

Comment: El error en la console es el siguiente: modificar.php:200 Uncaught TypeError: theForm.submit is not a function
    at security (modificar.php:200)
    at HTMLDivElement.onclick (modificar.php:186)

Comment: Sin ver más de tu código, ese error no me dice mucho. ¿Estás comprobando en **borrar.php** si te llega el campo con **name="id"**? Porque estar, se está enviando. Al menos en mis pruebas.

Comment: Si, formulario lleva funcionando perfectamente meses ya, ahora que necesito que pida una fonfirmación es cuando estoy teniendo el problema, no estoy cambiando nada del formulario, sólo el js

Comment: en lugar de poner el php en el value, intenta hacer un `echo` de la línea entera del input

Comment: Prueba esto: `var theForm = document.forms.namedItem( 'formborrar' );`

Comment: ¿Y lo que llamas problema que es? ¿Que no se envía el formulario? ¿Que se sigue enviando aunque le des a cancel en el alert? Cuanta más información nos des mejor podremos ayudarte.

Comment: El problema es que parece que el if es irrelevante, si en el boton de la funcion quito el type="submit" ya no valida el form, si lo pongo, lo valida

Comment: El código expuesto en la pregunta funciona, el error no se puede reproducir.

Answer (score 1):

Ahora ha quedado más claro lo que deseas conseguir.

El problema que pareces tener, es que tienes un **input** con **type="submit"**. Este **type** lo que hace es llamar siempre al **action** del formulario cuando se le hace **click**, por lo que por mucha validación que le estés poniendo en tu función **JS** se va a seguir enviando. Si cambias un par de cositas en el **HTML** y otra en el **JS**, te debería de funcionar.

**HTML**

```
<form action="borrar.php" method="post" name="formborrar">
  <input type="text" name="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" style="display: none;">
  <input class="btn" onclick="security()" value="Borrar Aviso" name="submit">
</form>
```

**JS**

```
function security(){
  var mensaje = confirm("¿Estás seguro de que quieres BORRAR este aviso?");
if (mensaje) {
  alert('SI');
  document.forms.namedItem('formborrar').submit();
}
else {
  alert('NO');
}
}
```

Prueba y nos cuentas

**EDIT**

Los **alert** los puedes quitar. Los dejé puestos para que veas que la condición del **if** está funcionando correctamente.